# Creating a 3D mesh on an Image3D Figure

Tags: mesh, image3d

I have a stack of images that I compile with the Image3D function. The resulting figure is 360x360x93 pixels and named "X". My goal is to mesh the figure.

I have defined points that correspond the the corners of the figure and tried to "stick" them on my figure:

```
coord = Join[{{1., 1., 1.}, {360., 1., 1.}, {360., 360., 1.}, {1., 
360., 1.}, {1., 1., 93.}, {360., 1., 93.}, {360., 360., 93.}, {1.,
 360., 93.}}, PixelValuePositions[X, 1]]
```

This returns a massive list of points and doesn't "stick" the points like I'd hoped. I'd like to be able to go on and run the following code to make the mesh:

```
boundaryElements = {TetrahedronElement[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 
  8}, {1, 2, 7, 6}, {4, 5, 9, 3}, {1, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 7, 8, 3}}]};
 bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> coord, 
"BoundaryElements" -> boundaryElements];
 bmesh["Wireframe"]
```

I've tried many different things to make the points "stick" to my figure but I have been unsuccessful each time. I've also defined a separate variable as the coordinates and used the Join function in the following way:

```
coord2 = Join [coordinates, PixelValuePositions[X,1]]
```

I have been able to create an empty rectangular box of dimensions 360x360x93 and create a mesh of it, but I cannot replicate this on an actual figure.

Comment: Have you seen [`ImageMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageMesh.html)?

Comment: Also, if you could provide `X`, it would make it easier to help answer your question.

Comment: How could I upload a 3D figure here? I'd be happy to do so!

Comment: ImageMesh is the closest I've gotten - thank you!!

Comment: I've seen people use Pastebin in the past.

Comment: I couldn't save and upload the 3D but here is a 2D shot. This is actually after I run the EdgeDetect to make the "fibers" inside easier to see. I'm trying to mesh the original image that just looks like a big orange block.
https://imagebin.ca/v/35NVraHw9CH3

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about what your goal is. Are you wanting to turn a 3D image into a mesh, or show the image and mesh objects together?

Comment: I want to create a finite element mesh to analyze the 3D image parts. I want it to mesh around the "fibers" inside. In the Mathematica help files they create meshes of set 3D figures, such as the airplane - that is what I am trying to do with my figure.

Comment: It sounds like `ImageMesh` is what you want then, right? You may need to do `ImageMesh[ColorNegate[X]]` if you're getting the complement of what you want.

Comment: Chip - that works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear. I realized you can insert your data into your question by converting it into a GIF: `Export["animation.gif", Image3DSlices[X]]`. This way I can give this question an answer, rather than just a string of comments.